# Race condition on Firefox when trying to redirect after setting cookies

Tags: javascript, firefox, request, race-condition

So I have this small web app written in TypeScript with NestJS, RxJS combo for the backend and React in the frontend.

At some point, **I am getting some authentication cookies in the back from another website and then send a redirect response (302) with set-cookies headers to be used in the front when redirecting.**

1. This works fine on Chrome and Safari (Last versions)
2. This doesn’t work on Firefox (Last version)
3. But if I use `location.assign` directly on Firefox after the request, it works.

I'm guessing here that cookies are set from the `set-cookie` headers but it happens after Firefox tries to redirect which causes the issue: 401 error and no redirection.

Frontend code is very close to:

```js
fetch(`/api/connect-to-other-sub-domain/`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 302) location.assign('https://www.other.domain.com/');
        else handleError()
      })
      .catch(location.assign('https://www.other.domain.com/')) // Still go to other subdomain and connect manually
```

As you can see, there is a callback that use the `location.assign` function but I actually don't know on Chrome and Safari if this callback is triggered or if the browser simply follows the redirection properly.

I try using a 303 code instead but it is the same, works on Safari and Chrome and not on Firefox.

Other things to know:

- `www.other.domain.com` is a signup page but directly connects the user if the right cookies are present.
- Frontend page is like `www.app.domain.com` and cookies are set in back with `Domain` `.domain.com` and `SameSite=Lax` (which is default)
- Everything is HTTPS